# Controller - Search System Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a search system on Laravel 5.6. 
My real problem is the function "search" to create in my Controller...

I have a table named **clubs** and I want to get the **name_club** only.

In my **index.blade.php** I have this

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-prepend">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

In my **ClubController** I have this

```
public function index()
{
   $clubs = Club::oldest()->paginate(5);
   return view('admin.index', compact('clubs'))
             ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
}
```

For my function search() I don't know the syntax...  I don't really understand how to integrate my pagination and the "name_club" field in my search function

```
public function search(Request $request)
{   
    $search = $request->get('search');
}
```

**Route** 
    Route::resource('/admin', 'ClubController');
    Route::resource('/search','ClubController@search');

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can paginate any regular query:

```php
$search = $request->get('search');
$clubs = Club::oldest()
             ->where('name_club', 'like', "%$search%")
             ->paginate(5);
```

For more advanced searches I would recommend using [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scout). Then it becomes something like this:

```php
$search = $request->get('search');
$clubs = Club::search($search)->paginate(5);
```

Comment: thank you for your help. When I tape a word on search bar I will wish now to return to page admin.index where there are all records and recuperate only the record. 
Is it the route.php seems to be ok ?